# Function doesnt remove from eventListener

Tags: javascript, event-listener

The problem is that i cant remove a function from the eventListener.
I have the following method from the class:

```
setNavigator(nav){
renderNavigatorGraphic(nav.querySelector("canvas"));

var span = nav.querySelector(".graphic-overview > .selector > span"),
    selectorWidth = this.selectorWidth = span.clientWidth,
    selectorBorder = this.selectorBorder = parseFloat(
                          getComputedStyle(span, "::before")
                          .getPropertyValue("border-left-width")
                        ),
    eventNames = (isMobileDevice())
                    ?["touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend"]
                    :["mousedown", "mousemove", "mouseup", "mouseleave"];

span.addEventListener(eventNames[0], eventHandler, false);
span.addEventListener(eventNames[2], removeEventHandler, false);
if(eventNames[3]) span.addEventListener(eventNames[3], removeEventHandler, false);

function resizeleft(){console.log("left");}
function resizeright(){console.log("right");}
function move(){console.log("move");}
function renderNavigatorGraphic(canvas){ console.log(canvas) }
function eventHandler(e){
  var x = e.offsetX,
      eventName = eventNames[1];

  if(x > selectorBorder){
    if(x < (selectorWidth - selectorBorder)){
      console.log("move");
      span.addEventListener(eventName, move, false);
    }else{
      console.log("resizeRight");
      span.addEventListener(eventName, resizeright, false);
    }
  }else{
    console.log("resizeLeft");
    span.addEventListener(eventName, resizeleft, false);
  }
}
function removeEventHandler(){
  console.log("removeEvent", this, eventHandler);
  span.removeEventListener(eventNames[1], eventHandler);
}
function isMobileDevice() {
  return (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('IEMobile') !== -1);
};
}
```

This method get node which have an element ("span"). This element resizes if user clicks on its border or moves if he clicks on its inner body. As you can see, when user click on element it get a position of cursor and than decided to which function use for "move" event. But when the user moved out the element or ended holding a mouse or touching on this element (simply - ended resizing or dragging element) i need to remove the eventHandler from "move" event, but this doesnt happen. The question - why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if these are the two events you are trying to remove

```
span.addEventListener(eventNames[2], removeEventHandler, false);
if(eventNames[3]) span.addEventListener(eventNames[3], removeEventHandler, false);
```

then you need to call
 `.removeEventListener('event', namedFunction, options)`
 instead of 
`.addEventListener(event, namedFunctions, options)`
important takeaway there is you can only remove named functions from an event listener, you can not remove an anonymous function that is handling the event if I remember correctly

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but i remove named function (name of this function "eventHandler"). It is true that .removeEventListener removes only named functions because it store only thier name, but if it is true why it cant remove "eventHandler" from "move" event? If i misunderstand you, please tell me please so what do you mean more deployed.

Comment: you have a this function `function removeEventHandler(){
  console.log("removeEvent", this, eventHandler);
  span.removeEventListener(eventNames[1], eventHandler);
}` that I believe is being used to remove the event handle, but you're not passing in any arguments to correspond with what you're calling in the function. so if you have `someThing.addEventListener('click', handleSomething)` you in turn want to say `someThing.removeEventListener('click', handleSomething)`

Comment: Ok, now i have understood you. Thanks, your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to remove "eventHandler" function, but i need to remove either of "move", "risizeleft" and "resizeright" functions. To solve this problem i created a variable that has name of current function and than remove it from "move" event when it is needed.

```
setNavigator(nav){
renderNavigatorGraphic(nav.querySelector("canvas"));

var span = nav.querySelector(".graphic-overview > .selector > span"),
    selectorWidth = this.selectorWidth = span.clientWidth,
    selectorBorder = this.selectorBorder = parseFloat(
                          getComputedStyle(span, "::before")
                          .getPropertyValue("border-left-width")
                        ),
    eventNames = (isMobileDevice())
                    ?["touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend"]
                    :["mousedown", "mousemove", "mouseup", "mouseleave"],
    functionHandler;

span.addEventListener(eventNames[0], eventHandler, false);
span.addEventListener(eventNames[2], removeEventHandler, false);
if(eventNames[3]) span.addEventListener(eventNames[3], removeEventHandler, false);

function resizeleft(){console.log("left");}
function resizeright(){console.log("right");}
function move(){console.log("move");}
function renderNavigatorGraphic(canvas){ console.log(canvas) }
function eventHandler(e){
  var x = e.offsetX,
      eventName = eventNames[1];

  if(x > selectorBorder){
    if(x < (selectorWidth - selectorBorder)){
      functionHandler = move;
    }else{
      functionHandler = resizeright;
    }
  }else{
    functionHandler = resizeleft;
  }

  span.addEventListener(eventName, functionHandler, false);
}
function removeEventHandler(){
  span.removeEventListener(eventNames[1], functionHandler);
}
function isMobileDevice() {
  return (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('IEMobile') !== -1);
};
}
```